# Polars - How to fill_null with mode on column (&str)

Tags: rust-polars

I'm trying out polars (Rust) on kaggle titanic dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic/data), and there is a column called "Cabin" where there are null values.

I've been trying to use `fill_null` and setting that to the mode of that column, however it doesn't seem to change it?

```rust
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let q = LazyCsvReader::new("data/train.csv")
        .has_header(true)
        .finish()?;

    let df = q
        .collect()?;

    let fill = df.clone()
        .lazy()
        .with_columns([col("Cabin").fill_null(col("Cabin").mode())])
        .collect()?;

    println!("{:?}", df.null_count());
    println!("{:?}", fill.null_count());

    Ok(())
}
```

The output of that is

```
shape: (1, 12)
┌─────────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───┬────────┬──────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ PassengerId ┆ Survived ┆ Pclass ┆ Name ┆ … ┆ Ticket ┆ Fare ┆ Cabin ┆ Embarked │
│ ---         ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆   ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ u32         ┆ u32      ┆ u32    ┆ u32  ┆   ┆ u32    ┆ u32  ┆ u32   ┆ u32      │
╞═════════════╪══════════╪════════╪══════╪═══╪════════╪══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 0           ┆ 0        ┆ 0      ┆ 0    ┆ … ┆ 0      ┆ 0    ┆ 687   ┆ 2        │
└─────────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───┴────────┴──────┴───────┴──────────┘
shape: (1, 12)
┌─────────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───┬────────┬──────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ PassengerId ┆ Survived ┆ Pclass ┆ Name ┆ … ┆ Ticket ┆ Fare ┆ Cabin ┆ Embarked │
│ ---         ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆   ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ u32         ┆ u32      ┆ u32    ┆ u32  ┆   ┆ u32    ┆ u32  ┆ u32   ┆ u32      │
╞═════════════╪══════════╪════════╪══════╪═══╪════════╪══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 0           ┆ 0        ┆ 0      ┆ 0    ┆ … ┆ 0      ┆ 0    ┆ 687   ┆ 2        │
└─────────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───┴────────┴──────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Can you produce a MRE (without an external dataset)?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this whole area, what's an MRE ? I also just found out that  because the most common value in this column is null, the mode would evaluate to null and therefore fill_null would set all the null to null. 

I'm not sure if this is intended behavior but I guess I gotta find another way

Comment: Oops, I added this same answer without seeing your comment. But if you still want the "mode" you can evaluate that by having a version where the nulls are filtered out and only take mode on what's left, then use that to do the real one. This could be done single pass but you'd need to implement your own mode_exclude_null. With this tiny dataset it wouldn't matter though

Comment: @kasn https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check in the csv, the most common element is null, which should count as "the most occurring value." in [mode()](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.mode)

So, it appears what's happening is you're saying replace all null with null.

Try picking something other than mode, or do a filter then mode on that result and you should see it replace the values.

Comment: This one works best, it replaces the nulls with the first mode. `col("Cabin").fill_null(col("Cabin").drop_nulls().mode().head(Some(1))`